# VCS Triggering not working correctly with TFS2010 as VCS

Tags: c#, vb6, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Would anyone have examples of VCS Trigger Rules for TFS2010?  I posted this question on the TC forum. Thought I would ask here too. http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/451874

I have 2 build Servers.  One server builds .NET code, the other will do a full continuous integration build of .NET and VB6 code. Both have their own default database and build agent however both are looking at the same TFS repository. I'm trying to set up rules that will prevent build triggering on certain files and file types that are checked in and when out (Non-TeamCity) nightly automated build checks-in versioning files as listed in the rules below:

Right now I have VCS Triggering set up on both build servers as follows:

Per-Checkin Triggering

```
 * Trigger Build on each check-in
 * Include several check-ins in a build if they are from the same committer
```

Quiet Period Settings:
Custom Quiet Period: 1000 seconds on first build server and 1800 seconds on second server.

VCS Trigger Rules:

```
+:.
-:**AssemblyInfo.vb
-:**AssemblyInfo.cs
-:**ProjectInfo.vb
-:**ProjectInfo.cs
-:**ProjectInfo.h
-:**.config
-:**.xml
-:**.bat
```

Now can I verify that my rule syntax is correct?  I've turned on the debug.vcs preset.

Any advice and/or help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: Just try checking-in one of those files and see if the build gets triggered.

Comment: We have. It does. That's why I'm asking. I did manage to take a wild guess and entered a few rules something like:
+:root=$\PROJ1\Folder1\Subfolder1\AssemblyInfo.cs and this appears to have worked but I was hoping to get some validation and/or confirmation from someone that has experience doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add trigger rules. If you want to exclude all AssemblyInfo.cs and .config files then following should work. I haven't tried it but should work.

```
+:.
-:AssemblyInfo.cs
-:**.config
```

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-TriggerRulesExample

Comment: Interesting. It hasn't been working till I added the "root" syntax yesterday after I posted this thread.

Comment: It appears I may have worked out the issue with the syntax. I thought I would post this in case anyone else has the same questions. 
Eample: -:root=$/<tfsprojectname>/<folders>/filestoinclude_or_exclude
-:root=$/AHLTA/Current/**.xml
-:root=$/AHLTA/Current/**.bat